# Failed to download Spring dependencies in Intellij

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

I'm following some tutorials in order to learn Spring but every time I try to create a new Spring project in IntelliJ I get a "Failed to download" error.

[image: Failed to download error message]

After some investigation, I found out that the issue stands in the Central Repository no longer supporting insecure communication over plain HTTP. [Issue Solution](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334)

My problem is that I don't know where should I perform these changes. So in which are in Intelijj should I make these changes?

Comment: You have to upgrade Apache Maven to most recent version or IDEA IntelliJ or you need to fix your configuration cause Maven Central is not available via http anymore only via https https://blog.sonatype.com/central-repository-moving-to-https I strongly recommend to go via https and not http anymore ....

Comment: Can you try to `mvn --version` on plain command line and post which Maven version you are using?

Comment: I'm currently using the version 3.6.1 of Maven, but I don't know where to fix maven configuration in Intellij to enable Maven Central through https